# Delete Orchard CMS content type via command line

Tags: orchardcms

Is there a way via the command line to delete a content type? I created one that seems to be bombing out. Actually the error is: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Contrib.DateTimeField.Settings.DateTimeFieldSettings', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Orchard.Fields.Settings.DateTimeFieldSettings'.

I just want to delete it and create another content type. Can I do this via the command line? I can't really do it via the admin page because I get the above error when I try to edit the content type.

Comment: Looks like a badly-compiled site more than a bug.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you have a code dependent on old, pre-1.5 DateTime field which hasn't been updated. I guess you have been upgrading to 1.5, am I right? Please give some more info about your scenario.

Comment: Interestingly I didn't start with a pre-1.5 site. This was a fresh 1.5 site. I did, somewhere along the way, download a DateTime field module (don't ask me which one). I honestly don't know when one I selected for my datetime field for a new Events content type. But now it's a corrupt type and I need to delete but can't from the UI.