# Reset the 'Custom Forms' Content Type in Orchard CMS having issues

Tags: asp.net, command-line, content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have mixed up the Content Type `Custom Forms` default settings. And it seems not usable anymore after some tweaks and settings.

Now it seems that I have to reinstall the orchard as whole. I'm in initial stage of the setup so it is possible for me to start afresh but I wanted to know regarding how to reset the `Content Type` to default settings using Orchard Command line or any other simpler way.

Please note: There is a question on deleting a `Content Type` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12890992/468718) but it seems that is also not answered yet. From an youtube video [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12890992/468718) I found to command to enable or disable the modules using command such as `feature enable <ModuleName>`

> But how to reset the Content Type that is still the question.

I have very short timeline for building the things now, and researching is taking too much time.

Hint or Help towards the solution would be kind of you.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this. What specifically did you do to Custom Forms, add/remove parts?

Comment: Yes. Can you tell me what are the default parts and (if any) fields ? (in the answer may be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look in the Migrations.cs of the CustomForms module source code, [online here](http://orchardcustomforms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b5ccdaed10ff#Migrations.cs), you can see what parts are being added to it.

So the relevant code is

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("CustomForm",
            cfg => cfg
                .WithPart("CommonPart")
                .WithPart("TitlePart")
                .WithPart("AutoroutePart", builder => builder
                    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AllowCustomPattern", "true")
                    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AutomaticAdjustmentOnEdit", "false")
                    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions", "[{Name:'Title', Pattern: '{Content.Slug}', Description: 'my-form'}]")
                    .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.DefaultPatternIndex", "0"))
                .WithPart("MenuPart")
                .WithPart("CustomFormPart")
                .DisplayedAs("Custom Form")
                .Draftable()
            );
```

The parts are therefore:

- CommonPart
- TitlePart
- AutoroutePart
- MenuPart
- CustomFormPart

I would recommend taking a look at this tutorial if you are having any problems: [DevDirective](http://devdirective.com/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha)

Do you really need to add/remove parts from this Content Type?

Comment: I was just trying to create a contact form using Custom Form which I saw in a video tutorial on orchard site but it all got wrong then as I was not referring video while doing the R&D. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries, best way to learn Orchard is to mess around with it, in my most humble opinion. You are bound to break some stuff :)

Comment: I have almost the same problem but i have completely deleted my contect type .. is there any simple way to recreate everything ? uninstall an re-install a module ?